# Beginner C - Print user's float inputs in reverse order

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm writing a program that uses 1 statement to read 6 floating numbers from user.  Then have it print the 6 numbers in 3 lines, with all of following requirements:

(1) the numbers are printed in the reverse order that they are read in

(2) they are on 3 lines: 1 number on the first line, 2 numbers on the next line, 3 numbers on the last line

(3) line up the numbers so they are in column format, right justified, with 1 digit after the decimal point

---

Here's my attempt for the first 2 requirements

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    //variable definitions
    float f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6;

    printf ("Enter 6 float numbers, separated by commas: ");

    scanf ("%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4,%f5,%f6",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4,&f5,&f6);

    printf ("%f6\n",f6);
    printf ("%f5,%f4\n",f5,f4);
    printf ("%f3,%f2,%f1\n",f3,f2,f1);

    return 0;

}
```

To my beginner mind, it makes perfect sense.

Here's the result when i run it

> Enter 6 float numbers, separated by commas: 0.2,3.2,0.1,0.5,0.6,0.7
>
> the numbers are:
>
> -107374176.0000006
>
> -107374176.0000005,-107374176.0000004
>
> -107374176.0000003,-107374176.0000002,0.2000001
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

All of them are garbage outputs except for the last one. Appreciate all the helps!

Comment: They're garbage because you never initialized them. The `scanf` call also didn't set them because the text you entered didn't match the format string so `scanf` just failed - which you didn't notice because you didn't check `scanf`'s return value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format

```
scanf ("%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4,%f5,%f6",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4,&f5,&f6);
```

expects a `1` after the first `float` and before the following comma, a `2` after the next etc.

It should be

```
scanf ("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4,&f5,&f6);
```

Since the separating digits weren't provided, the second conversion (and the following) failed, and the other `float`s remained uninitialised.

Comment: I knew it was something very simple that's overlooked by a beginner but couldn't figure what for the life of me.

Comment: The same goes for your printf() statement. Use %f by itself for each variable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the format:

```
scanf ("%f1,%f2,%f3,%f4,%f5,%f6",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4,&f5,&f6);
```

Should be

```
scanf ("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",&f1,&f2,&f3,&f4,&f5,&f6);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format to print float numbers is:

```
printf("%.1f", variable);
```

In this example the number in `variable` will be printed with 1 digit after the decimal point.

Comment: I'll be constructive and say that it will not be printed with 2 digits after decimal point with that format string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry I made a mistake with the keys, it was .2f