# Reverse a float number C

Tags: c

I am learning C. We use `scanf` and `printf` for input and output data.
We have a question in our lesson: Reverse a float number.

My programming skills are good and I can do this easily.
For example one of my ideas is to convert a `float` number to `int` by power 10 then reverse it and convert it to `float` again. There are lots of other ideas too.

But we have a limit in our question. Use `scanf` features to reverse number.

*I ask my teacher to give me a code for this. He gave below code. I am sorry because I don't understand code clearly. This code give 12 and 33 for 12.33 but this code doesnt work for 12.00001 because we get 12 and 1. When we get this number we reverse them and print it. My teacber asks me a way to solve this but I can't find a way. It is not neccesary to exist a way but Is it possible to help me?*

My teacher code:

```
int main(){
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d.%d", &a, &b);
    printf("a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you use `scanf`, use it to scan as a `string`, then you use loop to print it backwards.

Comment: I don't think that "use scanf()" means "and nothing else". I cannot imagine that other mechanisms like looping over a character array is excluded.

Comment: so I have to get string of number and reverse that array of char. There is no special code to do this for me automatically? (special code in scanf())

Comment: [Print user's float inputs in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446506/beginner-c-print-users-float-inputs-in-reverse-order) Hey, Probably this link will help you.

Comment: "Print user's float inputs in reverse order Hey, Probably this link will help you" I check it. it is not related.

Comment: [Print user's float inputs in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446506/beginner-c-print-users-float-inputs-in-reverse-order) Hey, Probably this link will help you.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you want. Please [edit] your question and show some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Please ask your teacher to give you real assignments and not what-if-you-mounted-wings-on-this-pig-would-it-fly assignments. I would hazard a guess that "nobody" uses scanf to *reverse* a **floating point number** and thus you won't find many examples of this on the web. It sounds like this teacher has found an interesting little tidbit in the C language or runtime and wants to show off.

Comment: I update my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If don't want any calculation then get it in String format and then reverse it.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 

void main(){  
  char str[20];  

  printf("Enter number: "); 
  scanf( "%s" , str );


  printf("\nReverse Number is: %s",strrev(str));  

}
```

Comment: There is a constraint in the question: **Use scanf features to reverse number**

Comment: Never use `gets`. It's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: My bad , I forgot to delete gets

Comment: maybe there is no way. I will use this way and ask my teacher. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure about that. scanf doesn't have any feature like that so far my knowledge. All it returns successfully read charecters that's all.

Comment: `conio.h` and `getche` make your code 100% non-portable outside of DOS/windows. Use `getchar()` to hold the terminal window open instead.

Comment: Yeah I do agree conio.h and getche was totally unnecessary. We don't need neither getche or getchar for modern compilers like Dev C++ / Code blocks or Visual Studio etc

Comment: Hopefully my answer served your purpose, Amin?

Comment: Exactly how portable is `strrev()` anyway?

Comment: your answer is good and work but it doesn't same as my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#define MAX 20

void main(void) {
  char str[MAX];  
  int i;
  printf("Enter number: "); 
  scanf( "%s" , str );

  for (i=0;i<MAX; i++){
      printf("%c",str[MAX-1-i]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer is nice but why are you unnecessarily looping from the end of the array while you haven't populated it completely?

Comment: @ Andrew, I thought the max length was 20 but it would be more elegant to use strlen of str i.e `strlen(str)`